# How do I perform cell selection animations while using reloadData?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView`, and I override `setSelected` in the `UICollectionViewCell` subclass to perform a little bounce animation when the user selects the cell.

The problem is that on selection of the cell, the very selection of the cell alters the data for the other cells (for instance, imagine the other cells have a label in each one that has the amount of cells selected displayed). So I call `collectionView.reloadData()` so that all the other cells update as well to show the new data (for instance, the amount of cells selected in a label).

However, this `reloadData()` call seems to reset the `UICollectionView` completely. Any animations taking place are stopped and the cells are simply updated without animation.

How do I have the cell selection animation, **and** update the other cells at the same time?

I've tried calling `reloadData()` only after the animation has completed, but this makes it look like there's lag/delay in updating the other cells (as it doesn't update them until a moment after when the animation finishes), which doesn't look very good.

Similarly, I've tried calling `reloadItemsAtIndexPaths:` (and exclude the selected cell that will animate), but for whatever reason with collection views this method seems *really* slow. Like there's a noticeable amount of lag after pressing it.

What should I be doing here? What's the standard for reloading data without the collection view destroying in-progress animations?

Comment: The way I would do it is to wait for the animation to complete and then call reloadData(). If you are allowing multiple selections at the same time, you can have your animation completion look at a variable that keeps track of whether any other animations are in flight before doing the call to reloadData().

Answer (score 1):

Reloading throws away the existing cells and creates (or reuses) new ones. So any animation is inherently destroyed. So, don't reload.

Instead, update your data model as usual and then get the currently visible index paths and associated cells and directly update those cells.